# How can I remove a site from the reading list in Safari on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari, reading-list

How do I edit the items in my "reading list" in Safari?  Unlike bookmarks, there doesn't seem to be an "edit" option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove an item, just swipe your finger to left over that particular entry. A red "delete" button will pop up.

Comment: You can swipe to the left or the right.  This trick will delete items from a list in many applications.